# Send File via jQuery Ajax $.post() Function

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can i send File variable Through Jquery $.post function .Thanks in Advance .

`var file=("#File").val();
$.post("process.php",{sFile:file},function(data)
{
    // html(data); 
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: RRRRRRRRRTTTTTTTTTTFFMMMMMMMM....???? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ look up `multipart/form-data`